# Metatrader 4 control via tcp/ip

Tags: metatrader4

[Here Malte talking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776726/how-can-i-reverse-engineer-a-network-protocol-metatrader-4/5413649#5413649) about MT4 Server API. Could anybody tell me some simple "how to"?

- where to get the DLL, install and run it inside the mt4 terminal
- any known "protocol commands" via the API (as Malte told, it is undocumented)

So, i don't want reverse engineer the metatrader protocol, but want use the official api and need some more info about it.

thanx for any pointer in advance ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reversed engineered the protocol to the point where I realised that it changes slightly for each broker and can be updated on the fly with LiveUpdate.exe In short it is near impossible to reverse engineer a general reliable solution.

Comment: Would you mind publishing what you found?

Answer (score 1):

Note: MT4 uses the standard FIX Protocol which is documented here: http://www.fixprotocol.org/

Comment: would you, Joseph, kindly provide any relevant source **citation** confirming this? Thanks.